# Could not parse the remainder: 'slug=blog.slug' from ''blog_details'slug=blog.slug'

Tags: python, django, slug, slugify

i am using slug field in my blogs. here's how i am creating slugs
views.py

```
def Creating_blog(request):
    form=BlogForm()
    if User.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=='POST':
                form=BlogForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid:
                    blog_obj=form.save(commit=False)
                    blog_obj.author=request.user
                    title=blog_obj.blog_title
                    blog_obj.slug = title.replace(' ','-') + '-'+ str(uuid.uuid4())
                    blog_obj.save()
                    return redirect('index')
    return render(request,'blogs/creatingblog.html',context={'form':form})
```

Using slug to lead to the blog details page

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">Read More</a>
```

but whenever i click on that it shows me

```
raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: 'slug=blog.slug' from ''blog_details'slug=blog.slug'
```

i have tried with slugify too

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug|slugify %}">Read More</a>
```

but it remains the same

help me out please.

Comment: Don't need to mention two times slug
```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details'  blog.slug|slugify %}">Read More</a>
````

Answer (score 0):

As @Dev already mentions, you can simply do:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_details' blog.slug %}">Read More</a>
```

Don't need to 'slugify' it either, as its already a slug.

Additionally, but unrelated, I'd recommend using Django's [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/).